# Adding a new directory to existing repository

Tags: git

I have a folder containing source code that I would like to add to an existing git repository.  I first do the init, add ., and commit commands. When I push to origin master, it tells me

```
error: failed to push some refs to '.../project.git'
```

And so I do pull origin master, and it adds a local copy of the existing project. When I then try to add my new folder with source code, it shows

```
modified: new_project_folder (modified content)
```

and

```
no changes added to commit
```

What should I do in order to add this new folder into the existing master branch?

Comment: When you get the first message ("failed to push some refs"), Git also tells you *why*. Please include the complete output from `git push`.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you do the init again?

Go back to the one you just pulled, put in your code, then do:

```
git add .
git commit -m "New module blah...'
```

and then push.

One thing that is a tad bit confusing in git is when you add directories, it echoes just the dir and so leaves you with the impression that maybe the contents were not added. They were.

Comment: Well, I'm really confused at this point. So I created a new directory and did a pull. It then says a pull is not possible...unmerged changes. So, I see where some people suggest 'git reset --hard origin/master'. I do this, but when I pull it simply says master -> FETCH_HEAD Already up-to-date, and no files are actually pulled down locally.

Comment: Yeah when you reset, you are resyncing to the remote master so that is right. Ok, so now that you have reset, go put the files in the new dir, where you want them and then do the sequence above.

Comment: Strangely enough, it only added an empty directory whose name is the parent folder of my new directory that I want to add.

Comment: Would it be easier to just rm what exists in the master branch and then just add everything together?

Comment: I wouldn't start rm'ing things. If it added the parent dir, that must be the dir that is under the root of the git project. Probably best to make ABSOLUTELY certain that the directory tree is the way you want it, then do the add.

Answer (score 0):

Is your new folder imported from another git repository? Check for .git folder inside it and remove it if presented. And make git add again.

If your new folder is empty then simply create empty file inside it